# Flask: Decorator to verify JSON and JSON Schema

Tags: python, flask, decorator, jsonschema, python-decorators

I have a flask application with calls expecting JSON payload. Before each call is processed, I have a 2-step error checking process:

- Assert that the payload is a valid JSON
- Assert that the JSON payload complies with a specific schema

Which is implemented in the following fashion:

```
@app.route('/activate', methods=['POST'])
def activate():
    request_id = request.__hash__()

    # Assert that the payload is a valid JSON
    try:
        input = request.json
    except BadRequest, e:
        msg = "payload must be a valid json"
        return jsonify({"error": msg}), 400

    # JSON Schema Validation
    try:
        validate(request.json, app.config['activate_schema'])
    except ValidationError, e:
        return jsonify({"error": e.message}), 400
```

Since this code is duplicated over many calls, I wonder If I can elegantly move it to a decorator, something in the formof:

```
@validate_json
@validate_schema(schema=app.config['activate_schema'])
@app.route('/activate', methods=['POST'])
def activate():
    ....
```

The problem is that the `request` argument is implicit: I can refer to it within the function, but it is not a parameter to it. Therefore, I am not sure how to use it within the decorator.

**How can I implement the validation checks using Python decorators?**

Comment: I was kinda hoping there'd be a library for doing this. @Martijn's answer is pretty straightforward, but does anybody know of one?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Just use the `request` context global in your decorator. It is available *during any request*.

```
from functools import wraps
from flask import (
    current_app,
    jsonify,
    request,
)


def validate_json(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        try:
            request.json
        except BadRequest, e:
            msg = "payload must be a valid json"
            return jsonify({"error": msg}), 400
        return f(*args, **kw)
    return wrapper


def validate_schema(schema_name):
    def decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kw):
            try:
                validate(request.json, current_app.config[schema_name])
            except ValidationError, e:
                return jsonify({"error": e.message}), 400
            return f(*args, **kw)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Apply these decorators *before* applying the `@route` decorator; you want to register the wrapped function, not the original function for the route:

```
@app.route('/activate', methods=['POST'])
@validate_json
@validate_schema('activate_schema')
def activate():
    input = request.json
```

Comment: Does the order of the decorators matter? Should the `@app.route` decorator come first?

Comment: @AdamMatan: `@route()` registers the callable, it should come on top to be applied to the decorated view function. I'll add that as well as the implementations.

Comment: Shouldn't `@validate_json` go at the very bottom of the decorator list?

Comment: @StefanSeemayer: no, top to bottom is outer to inner ordering for decorators. So `activate()` is called by `validate_schema()` which is called by `validate_json()`; the latter is registered by `@app.route()` as the view handler.

Comment: @StefanSeemayer: so when a request comes in for the registered route, Flask calls `validate_json()`, which calls `validate_schema()` which calls the `activate()` function.

Comment: Ah my bad, application of decorators is bottom to top, but then the wrapped functions are applied top to bottom.

Answer (score 7):

now you can use `@expect_json` directly

For Example

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, g, url_for
from flask_expects_json import expects_json
# example imports
from models import User
from orm import NotUniqueError

app = Flask(__name__)

schema = {
    'type': 'object',
    'properties': {
        'name': {'type': 'string'},
        'email': {'type': 'string'},
        'password': {'type': 'string'}
    },
    'required': ['email', 'password']
}


@app.route('/register', methods=['POST'])
@expects_json(schema)
def register():
    # if payload is invalid, request will be aborted with error code 400
    # if payload is valid it is stored in g.data

    # do something with your data
    user = User().from_dict(g.data)
    try:
        user.save()
    except NotUniqueError as e:
        # exception path: duplicate database entry
        return jsonify(dict(message=e.message)), 409

    # happy path: json response
    resp = jsonify(dict(auth_token=user.encode_auth_token(), user=user.to_dict()})
    resp.headers['Location'] = url_for('users.get_user', user_id=user.id)
    return resp, 201
```

or

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_expects_json import expects_json


app = Flask(__name__)


schema = {
    'type': 'object',
    'properties': {
        'name': {'type': 'string',  "minLength": 4, "maxLength": 15},
        'mobile': {'type': 'string', "pattern": "^[1-9]{1}[0-9]{9}$"},
        'email': {'type': 'string', "pattern": "[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]"},
        'password': {'type': 'string', "pattern": "^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&+=]).*$"}
    },
    'required': ['name', 'mobile', 'email', 'password']
}


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
@expects_json(schema)
def index():
    values = request.get_json()
    print(values)
    return values
```

get more from [here](https://pypi.org/project/flask-expects-json/)

Answer (score 0):

A late answer, but you're probably looking for something like marshmallow (flask-marshmallow) or toastedmarshmallow.