# Reusing boilerplate code across flask apps

Tags: python, error-handling, flask, code-reuse, boilerplate

I have some error handling calls across many of my flask apps. For example, my 404 response is defined using the `@app.errorhandler` decorator:

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return jsonify({'status': 'error',
                    'reason': '''There's no API call for %s''' % request.base_url,
                    'code': 404}), 404
```

Since I have a significant amount of boilerplate code, I would like to put it in a common file and inherit, or import, my flask app from a single place.

Is it possible to inherit or import flask boilerplate code from a different module?

Comment: Perhaps you could write a boilerplate flask extension? http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/extensiondev/

Comment: use `Blueprint.app_errorhandler`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768825/flask-error-handler-for-blueprints

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure there is, but you need to parameterise the registrations.

Instead of using decorators, move the registration to a function:

```
def page_not_found(e):
    return jsonify({'status': 'error',
                    'reason': '''There's no API call for %s''' % request.base_url,
                    'code': 404}), 404


def register_all(app):
    app.register_error_handler(404, page_not_found)
```

then import `register_all` and call it with your `Flask()` object.

This uses the [`Flask.register_error_handler()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.register_error_handler) function instead of the decorator.

To support blueprints too, you'll need to wait for a next release of Flask (one including [this commit](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/commit/d4fec1454488687b574c545761c2869d3bb97ca6)), or use the decorator function directly:

```
app_or_blueprint.errorhandler(404)(page_not_found)
```

For a lot of these tasks, you can use a Blueprint as well, provided you use [`Blueprint.app_errorhandler()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Blueprint.app_errorhandler):

```
common_errors = Blueprint('common_errors')


@common_errors.errorhandler(404)    
def page_not_found(e):
    return jsonify({'status': 'error',
                    'reason': '''There's no API call for %s''' % request.base_url,
                    'code': 404}), 404
```

Not *everything* can be handled by a Blueprint, but if all you are registering is error handlers, a Blueprint is a good approach.

Import the blueprint as usual and register it to your app:

```
from yourmodule import common_errors
app.register_blueprint(common_errors)
```

Comment: Thanks! nice to see you again. If I understand you correctly, this solution only applies to error handling and not to other utility functions (like the one [in your previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24238851/51197). Would blueprints be the solution for that?

Comment: @AdamMatan: the decorators in that answer can be reused anywhere. They are *already* reusable.

Comment: Meaning that I can put them in a blueprint and register them elsewhere in an app?

Comment: @AdamMatan: Blueprints can be used to add template filters, template globals, template tests, request hooks, context processors, url defaults, etc. etc.

Comment: @AdamMatan: Just about anything you normally register *on the app* can also be registered *on a blueprint*, to either apply just to routes on the blueprint, or to everything (anything with `app_` in the name applies to all routes, everywhere).

Comment: Thanks. That seems like a very useful tool - started reading the documentation.